# debian redis update-rc.d errors - there is a loop between redis and nginx

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, redis, debian

tried to install redis as a service in debian 7 wheezy(redis version 7) by following the instructions from http://redis.io/topics/quickstart

but after running  sudo update-rc.d redis_6379 defaults

i get these errors

```
update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
insserv: warning: script 'redis_6379' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service nginx and redis_6379 if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service redis_6379 at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service nginx at depth 1
insserv: Stopping redis_6379 depends on nginx and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
```

Nginx init.d is

```
#! /bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          nginx
# Required-Start:    $all
# Required-Stop:     $all
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: starts the nginx web server
# Description:       starts nginx using start-stop-daemon
### END INIT INFO

PATH=/opt/nginx/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DAEMON=/opt/nginx/sbin/nginx
NAME=nginx
DESC=nginx

test -x $DAEMON || exit 0

# Include nginx defaults if available
if [ -f /etc/default/nginx ] ; then
        . /etc/default/nginx
fi

set -e
```

Redis init.d is

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Simple Redis init.d script conceived to work on Linux systems
# as it does use of the /proc filesystem.

REDISPORT=6379
EXEC=/usr/local/bin/redis-server
CLIEXEC=/usr/local/bin/redis-cli

PIDFILE=/var/run/redis_${REDISPORT}.pid
CONF="/etc/redis/${REDISPORT}.conf"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add header to **/etc/init.d/redis_6379**

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: redis_6379
# Required-Start:    $network $remote_fs $local_fs
# Required-Stop:     $network $remote_fs $local_fs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: start and stop redis_6379
# Description: Redis daemon
### END INIT INFO
```

and run

```
sudo update-rc.d redis_6379 defaults
```